# Why does my JS function not work after dynamically adding content to the page?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a javascript function that is defined in the beginning of my webpage. It is called when a row is clicked in my table.

here is my function:

```
    $(".info").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('movieid'));
    });
```

here is my what my table row looks like:

```
<tr class="info" movieid="123"><td>movie title</td></tr>
```

now that table is displayed when I first load the page, I can click the row and it will call the function correctly. I am trying to implement a search function for the table. I have the php script return table rows just like the one above, I add them to the table, but when I click the row that is returned from the php script, the javascript function isn't called. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? I've had no luck.

**EDIT**

here is my function to get the search results:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "www.mysite.com/core/search.php",
        data: { q: search_string},
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("table#movies").fadeOut();
            $("div#results-container").fadeIn();
            $("div#results").fadeIn();
            $("div#results").html(html);
        }
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: are you using AJAX to get content..

Comment: i'm using the ajax function to get the content

Comment: i updated my question to include the search function

Comment: ok then just use jquery on api.. as suggested in ans by all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the element dynamically so it is not registered when you set the click handler.

```
$("body").on("click", ".info", function(e) {
   ...
});
```

`body` usually works but ideally you'd want a DOM element as close to your selector `.info` as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

```
$("body").on("click", "tr", function(event){
    alert($(this).attr('movieid'));
});
```

By adding a "container", it will have an effect like `.live()`.

Comment: thanks for the help, but when I added the "table" part, the row doesn't click

Comment: about j query like this version deprecated  in j Query 1.7 and removed: 1.9

Answer (score 1):

Use j Query ready event

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(".info").on("click", "tr", function(event){
       alert($(this).attr('movieid'));
   });
});
```

Comment: I don't think you need `.ready` because the new elements are loaded after the DOM is loaded anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Add `.on` on `document` because you are adding `DOM` to document.

**Example**

```
$(document).on('click',".info",function(){
       alert($(this).attr('movieid'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You php script is most likely not adding the class to the table row.  Alter it to add that class.

Comment: i have the class added to the table row .. it outputs the same as before

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help from all of you guys. I was able to figure it out.. @jasen mentioned that you to declare it as a body tag. Here was the solution I was able to use:

```
$("body").on("click", ".info", function(event){
   alert($(this).attr('movieid'));
});
```

Thank you Derek as well.. you provided some useful examples for the future.

Answer (score 0):

First, specify a selector where all the `tr.info` node will be contained, now and in future. From your latest edit of the post, I believe that's `table#movies`.

Then attach event with `on` and specify the children selector `tr.info`:

```js
$('table#movies').on('click', 'tr.info', function () {
    alert($(this).attr('movie'));
});
```

See example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82tku/)