# jQuery Dialog box holding data after partial view refresh

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-dialog

I have a partial view that opens a dialog box for entering some data. Once the button is clicked, an Ajax call is performed to reset that partial view and another. When I step through the code, everything seems to work alright except that when I open the partial view back up it the data is still in the box. I found some success following this question [Caching issue with loading partial views into JQuery dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528196/caching-issue-with-loading-partial-views-into-jquery-dialogs) but when I implement that the button doesn't work the second time I use it. My code is below:

jQuery and Ajax that refreshes the view and view that contains other partial views:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ChangeHeatName').click(function (e) {
        var tdata = $('#form1').serialize();
        var origname = $('#HeatNameDiv').find('input[name="heatName"]').first().val();
        var newname = $('#HeatNameDiv').find('input[name="updatedHeat"]').first().val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                mCollection: tdata,
                heatName: origname,
                updatedHeat: newname
            },
            url: '@Url.Action("ChangeHeatName","Home")',
            //url: "/Home/ChangeHeatName",
            success: function (result) { success(result); }
        });
    });


    function success(result) {

        $('#HeatNameDiv').dialog('close');
        //Ajax with problem
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("ButtonsPartial","Home")',
            success: function (result2) { $("#ButtonsPartial").html(result2); }
        });
        $("#Partial_Chem_Analysis").html(result);
    }
});
</script>

<section>
<div id ="ButtonsPartial" title="ButtonsPartial">
    @Html.Action("ButtonsPartial", "Home")
</div>
<div id="Partial_Chem_Analysis" title="Partial_Chem_Analysis">
    @Html.Action("PartialChemAnalysis", "Home", Model)
</div>
</section>
<section>
```

The partial view:

```
@using System.Data;
@using System.Dynamic;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Linq;
@model TheManhattanProject.Models.ButtonsModel


<div id="Chem_Buttons">
<h2 class="alignleft">Chemistry Table</h2>
<p class="alignright">Heat Name<input type="text" name="heat_name" value="@Model.heatName" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" style ="width:100px" readonly="true"/>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="Change_Heat_Name" value="Change_Heat_Name" name="action:Change_Heat_Name" type="button"> Change Heat Name</button>
Grade<input type="text" name="heat_grade" value="@Model.grade" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" style="width:100px" readonly="true"/>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="ChangeHeatGrade" value="ChangeHeatGrade" name="action:Change_Grade" type="button">Change Grade</button>
Delete Record<input type="text" name="delete_record" value="@Model.heatName" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" style ="width:100px" readonly="true"/>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="DeleteRecord" value="DeleteRecord" name="action:Delete_Record" type="button">Delete Record</button>
  </p>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>
<div id="HeatNameDiv" title="Change Heat Name">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeHeatName", "Home", "POST"))
   {
    <section>
        Heat Name:<input type="text" name="heatName" value="@Model.heatName" style ="width:100px" readonly="true"/>
        //Value staying to what was entered not ""
        Change to:<input type="text" name="updatedHeat" value="" style="width: 100px" />
        <input type="button" id="ChangeHeatName" name="ChangeHeatName" value="Change" />
    </section>
}
</div>

<div id="HeatGradeDiv" title="Change Heat Grade">
@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeGrade", "Home", "POST"))
{
    <section>
        Heat Grade:<input type="text" name="grade" value="@Model.grade" style ="width:100px" readonly="true"/>
        Change to:<input type="text" name="updatedGrade" value="" style="width: 100px" />
        <input type ="hidden" name="hiddenHeat" value ="@Model.heatName)" />
        <input type="button" id="ChangeGrade" name="ChangeGrade" value="Change" />
    </section>
}
</div>

<div id="DeleteRecordDiv" title="Delete Record">
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteRecord", "Home", "POST"))
{
<section>
    Heat Name:<input type="text" name="heatName" value="@Model.heatName" style ="width:100px" readonly="true"/>
    <input type="button" id="DeleteRecordBtn" name="DeleteRecordBtn" value="Delete" />
</section>
}
</div>
```

Comment: You are replacing the original button with the partial load. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674189/why-does-my-js-function-not-work-after-dynamically-adding-content-to-the-page/15674314#15674314

Comment: @Jasen The button, and that entire div is supposed to be replaced with that partial view. I'm not sure I understand

Comment: The event handler was tied to the original button that got replaced with a partial view load. After that it doesn't have a handler until you register it again or register the click handler to a parent DOM element the first time.

Comment: That makes more sense. Would making the Ajax call to the buttons partial view be the last thing that happened make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handler was tied to the original button that got replaced with a partial view load. After that it doesn't have a handler until you register it again or register the click handler to a parent DOM element the first time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // instead of this
    $('#ChangeHeatName').click(function (e) {
        ...
    });

    // do this
    $("body").on("click", "#ChangeHeatName", function(e) {
        ...
    });
});
```

Try to replace `"body"` with a static DOM element as close to your reloaded partial as possible.

```
$("#ButtonsPartial").on("click", "#ChangeHeatName", function(e) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: I tried doing that and when I click the button to execute the code it does nothing. I even checked in firebug and nothing happens

Comment: try just "body" since that shouldn't reload

Comment: With "body in there, it submits and the dialog box closes but when I open the box back up still has the last value I entered in it.

Comment: I got it working! With the part you gave with the "body" I needed to put "$('#HeatNameDiv').dialog('destroy').remove();" in the success